# How to fix ----- ./darknet: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, yolo, darknet

I'm getting trouble in yolo training in jupyter-notebook with using AWS SageMaker.

I wanna darknet-model to start training, but it doesn't work well.

I tried these code below, And all codes go well.

```
! conda install cudatoolkit -y
! conda install cudnn -y
! conda install -c fragcolor cuda10.0 -y
! conda update --all -y
```

I tried to train models...

```
! ./darknet detector train lamp.data yolov3-lamps.cfg darknet53.conv.74 -gpus 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

but this error happens.

```
./darknet: error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this (adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to your system):
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/ ./darknet detector train lamp.data yolov3-lamps.cfg darknet53.conv.74 -gpus 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while working on a g3 instance on AWS with all the deep learning services pre-installed. This service preinstalls a lot of cuda versions, so I had set my environment variables to cuda-10.1. On checking the usr/local/cuda folder - it is redirected to cuda-10.0 by default. I did the following to change the default settings.

Make the following changes in the make file (for working in GPU and cuDNN):

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=1
CUDNN_HALF=1
OPENCV=0
AVX=0
OPENMP=1
```

Check if the ARCH is correctly set for your GPU configuration. You can head to this [page](http://arnon.dk/tag/nvcc-flags/) to do so.

If you are using GPU = 1:
Check lines 110-129 in the make file and see if everything is directed to the compatible cuda version that you are currently using. Since I was using *cuda-10.1*, I changed it as so -

```
ifeq ($(GPU), 1)
COMMON+= -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda-10.1/include/
CFLAGS+= -DGPU
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin) #MAC
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
else
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand
endif
endif

ifeq ($(CUDNN), 1)
COMMON+= -DCUDNN
ifeq ($(OS),Darwin) #MAC
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cuda-10.1/include
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib -lcudnn
else
CFLAGS+= -DCUDNN -I/usr/local/cudnn/include
LDFLAGS+= -L/usr/local/cudnn/lib64 -lcudnn
endif
endif
```

After make the necessary changes, `make` the Makefile again to see them effective. This solved my problem and it started training.